# Can I return a struct a from a function that the struct is defined in? (c)

Tags: c, function, struct

I am trying to define a struct inside a function and return that struct at the end of the function, but can't figure out the right way to do this.
For example:

```
struct Animals test() {
    struct Animals {
         int* age;
         char* name;
    }
    return struct Animals;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work that way.  The struct needs to be defined at a scope where it's visible to all functions that use it.  If you're trying to create a type dynamically, C doesn't do that.

Comment: You also don't put a type name in the `return` statement, it has to be an expression.

Comment: You can malloc it and return a pointer to the created struct. If you allocate it statically it will end up in the stack frame of the function call and be invalid after it returns.

Comment: Struct definitions are not variables, they are type definitions. You define a struct first, then declare variables of that type later.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I return a struct a from a function that the struct is defined in?

No.

> I am trying to define a struct inside a function

Do not do that.  Define `struct` first.

```
struct Animals {
     int age;  // int makes more sense here than `int *`
     char* name;
};
```

Then return the `struct`.  The *value* of the object can be defined in `test()`, but the *structure* of the object should be defined outside and before `test()`.

```
struct Animals test(void) {
    //     v------ compound literal  -----------------v
    return (struct Animals){.age = 42, .name = "fred" };
}
```

Be careful with management of what member `.name` points to.